# Summing List of values with similar keys to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I take a list of values (percentages):

```
example = [(1,100), (1,50), (2,50), (1,100), (3,100), (2,50), (3,50)]
```

and return a dictionary:

```
example_dict = {1:250, 2:100, 3:150}
```

and recalculate by dividing by sum(example_dict.values())/100:

```
final_dict = {1:50, 2:20, 3:30}
```

The methods I have tried for mapping the list of values to a dictionary results in values being iterated over rather than summed.

---

**Edit:**
Since it was asked here are some attempts (after just writing over old values) that went no where and demonstrate my 'noviceness' with python:

```
{k: +=v if k==w[x][0] for x in range(0,len(w),1)}
```

invalid

```
for i in w[x][0] in range(0,len(w),1):
    for item in r:
        +=v  (don't where I was going on that one)
```

invalid again.

another similar one that was invalid, nothing on google, then to SO.

Comment: Show "the methods you have tried".

Comment: I don't understand final_dict..how is 250/100=50? or 100/100=20?

Comment: It appears that what's meant is that 250//(250+100+150) = 0.5, and 0.5 * 100 = 50 (i.e. a percentage).

Comment: So you want to take a list of tuples, map them into a dictionary where the keys come from the first values and the values from the sums of the seconds. Then you want to sum the values in the dictionary, then divide each value by 1/100th of that sum?

Comment: "the method you tried" now posted.  Didn't include because they all throw error and were so poor there was no value in including them.  Karl is correct on that the final result was to be a percentage.  I phrased this in two parts as I know I will have similar methods that require the stop point in the middle and no further modification to the values.  Mark's answer does this if the '*100 / total' is left off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
total = float(sum(v for k,v in example))
example_dict = {}
for k,v in example:
     example_dict[k] = example_dict.get(k, 0) + v * 100 / total
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/UtBA6)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Counter` class:

```
from collections import Counter
totals = Counter()
for k, v in example: totals.update({k:v})
total = sum(totals.values())
final_dict = {k: 100 * v // total for k, v in totals.items()}
```